# How to pass dynamic image links in an image slider getting from server using rest api in android

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I am creating an auto slider in android and it is working with `drawable` images i want to add images getting from server using rest `api` how can i do that please help here is my code. this is my adapter where i am passing `drawable` images to the slider...

```
public class HomeImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private int[] mImageIds = new int[]{R.drawable.slideone , R.drawable.slideone , R.drawable.slideone};

    public HomeImageAdapter(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mImageIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
        return view == o;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        container.addView(imageView , 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((ImageView) object);
    }

}
```

In the above code i want to pass array of images getting from server please help

Comment: you need to download the images first, or use one of image loading libraries (Picasso, Glide, Universal Image Loader, etc.)

Comment: Can you please show the sample code @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: Currently i am using Picasso for other images @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: pass the list of image URLs to adapter and load corresponding image in `instantiateItem`

Comment: I am not understanding it :( @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: do you have `array of images getting from server`?

Comment: Yes i have array of images i have created models using pojo

Comment: ok, then pass the array to the adapter. For example, in constructor. Then in `instantiateItem` get the item from the array, get the url from the item, and load it into ImgageView using Picasso